# why images not loading from xml file of url and not showing in table view

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

Am retrieving XML file from the url and i got the images through parsing it. My XML file consists like this,

```
<Products>
<products id="1">
<img>http://images.com/images/image1.jpg</img>
</products>
<products id="2">
<img>http://images.com/images/image2.jpg</img>
</products>
<products id="3">
<img>http://images.com/images/image3.jpg</img>
</products>
</Products>
```

The Tableviewcontroller.m has the code like this,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://images.com/Products.xml"];
 [self.tableView reloadData];}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return 1;}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [xmlParser.tweets count];}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Products";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];}
UIImage *currentTweet = [[xmlParser tweets] objectAtIndex:1];
cell.imageView.image = currentTweet;
[cell.contentView addSubview:self.productImage];
return cell;}
```

Here xmlParser is the object of class XMLParser and tweets is the array. The product image is reference of the UIImageview.
Now my problem is when i run the app it shows the image in tableview as a thumbnail picture, but i want to show image as the below screenshot i shown.

[image: Desired output]

Also am confused in referencing UIImage view in storyboard, when i define productImage as UIImageView in .h file and try to connect the storyboard it shows me error like Illegal Configuration: Connection "productImage" cannot have a prototype object as its destination. so kindly tell me how to connect it in storyboard too.

Kindly suggest me to solve this,

Comment: in that image url there is no image and all.........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Products";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];}

UIImage *currentTweet = [[xmlParser tweets] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIImageView *tweetImageView = [UIImageView alloc] 
                           initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,
                           cell.frame.size.width , cell.frame.size.height)];
tweetImageView.image = currentTweet;
[cell.contentView addSubview:tweetImageView];

return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return self.view.frame.size.height/3;
}
```

Comment: Your answer worked out but one small change is `[cell setBackgroundView:tweetImageView];` instead `[cell.contentView addSubview:tweetImageView];` Thanks a lot pranav and one more issue am getting an empty small space below the last image see this link    [link] http://www.freeimagehosting.net/qdyya [/link] for that image prob  tel me how to solve it

Comment: @sathya it's possibly the view (white color) on which you are adding table view or you have added more number of rows to your table view. Make the height of cell as (view'sHeight/3)

Comment: view'sHeight/3 is like i have to write a function that what you mean right? or do we have any option to set in stoaryboard

Comment: @sathya there is a delegate, I have added it in the answer. Plz do check Apple reference for the components that you are using...they have all this stuff documented.

Comment: am getting a prob like am retrieving all the images in table view listed in the XML file. if i need to show specific, i used the objectAtIndex:1 2,3 so on but this shows only the last image in all cells. wat i wanna do to get specific image from xml file listed in different cell with different images from xml file

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assign ID type to `UIImage` 
Try this code to load image for you cell

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[xmlParser tweets] objectAtIndex:1]];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *currentTweet = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
cell.imageView.image = currentTweet;
```

Comment: it showed me error like this  -[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71c3e00
and app terminated saying Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71c3e00'

Comment: can you check `[[xmlParser tweets] objectAtIndex:1]` either its returning string or not.

Comment: You are trying to access something which is not array, or array which contains 0 objects. Check `[xmlParser tweets]` is what class using this `NSLog(@"%@", [[xmlParser tweets] class]);`

Answer (score 1):

**1) Problem** : Getting a thumbnail image in table view but you want to show that image in background (complete cell width) Am i right??

**Solutions** :

**In below mentioned way your image can be spread in background**

```
 UIImage *currentTweet = [[xmlParser tweets] objectAtIndex:1];
 UIImageView *tweetImageView = [UIImageView alloc] 
                               initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,
                               cell.frame.size.width , cell.frame.size.height)];
 tweetImageView.image = currentTweet;
 [cell.contentView addSubview:tweetImageView];
```

**Another option is that you can set the background image of the cell like :**

```
[cell setBackgroundView:tweetImageView]
```

**Update :**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (cell == nil) 
     {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     }
     UIImage *currentTweet = [[xmlParser tweets] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     UIImageView *tweetImageView = [UIImageView alloc] 
                                   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,
                                   cell.frame.size.width , cell.frame.size.height)];
     tweetImageView.image = currentTweet;
     [cell.contentView addSubview:tweetImageView];
     return cell;
}
```

Dont create separate imageviews instead use one image view.

And for every row(indexPath.row) pass different image to the imageview.

For every row a new cell gets created an its new imageview will fetch corresponding image from array

Hope it helps
:)

Comment: ya i got it but as of i need three different images how can i assign to a single UIImageview variable

Comment: @sathya load image w.r.t table view row index, check my answer

Comment: @swati i had changed the objectAtIndex value as 0,1,2 respectively according to images but i retrieve the same image in all 3 cells how to assign seperate images for 3 cells

Comment: can u tell me how u r using 3 three indexes (please share the part of code related to this)

Comment: by the same way as you shown in above code i just changed the objectAtIndex as 0,1 and 2 respectively. Also given different name for UIImage and UIImageView to avoid name conflict

Comment: also i wanna tel one thing , am retirving the last image alone in all 3 cells, say `UIImage *currentTweet = [[xmlParser tweets] objectAtIndex:3];`

Comment: @swati am getting a prob like am retrieving all the images in table view listed in the XML file. if i need to show specific, i used the objectAtIndex:1 2,3 so on but this shows only the last image in all cells. wat i wanna do to get specific image from xml file listed in different cell with different images from xml file

Comment: dats y i suggested u to use indexpath.row >> this will fetch unique image from array and display different image in each cell

Comment: ya swati i used that but it retrives all the images from xml and showing all in table

Comment: ok, r u sure that array returs unique images, coz i doubt array contains 3 images but all are same not 3 different???

Comment: This is the output i got from that array - Products list (
    "<UIImage: 0x74986b0>",
    "<UIImage: 0x7497f30>",
    "<UIImage: 0x749abe0>"
)

Comment: i have updated the code, please have a look, i have changed the code of how cell is getting created.check inside if(cell==nil) condition. Hope this helps

Comment: no change swati it shows same. Actually i need to show only two images from the list of 3 images from array  eg- Products list ( "<UIImage: 0x74986b0>", "<UIImage: 0x7497f30>", "<UIImage: 0x749abe0>" ) if i say this two "<UIImage: 0x7497f30>", "<UIImage: 0x749abe0>" image alone in objectAtIndex:0 and objectAtIndex:1 in program am getting the last image "<UIImage: 0x749abe0>" in both 2 cells thats my prob hope u understood wat am saying